# Is it possible to inject static resources from other projects in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

By example, have a WEB project, but need add a custom static content from vendors without recompile the main jar project.

Is it possible to run the Spring Boot .jar file and give some argument to tell it to load other jars where different static contents are found or from code dynamically? For example:

- `1.jar` : `src/resources/static/vendor1/`
- `2.jar` : `src/resources/static/vendor2/`

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a property named `loader.path`. Quote from [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features)

> Comma-separated Classpath, such as lib,${HOME}/app/lib. Earlier
> entries take precedence, like a regular -classpath on the javac
> command line.